# mongodb query does not work

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection, and a part of my collection is here,

lets call this first array

```
$ho = array( 'a' => 
array (
'0' => '508bef9e6803fa6305000000',
'1' => '50901eac6803fafb0d000000',
'2' => '508bf3766803fa810f000000',
'3' => '50a2aeac6803fa150b000000',
'4' => '50a2ae846803fa140b000000',
'5' => '50a2ae616803fab706000000',
'6' => '50a2ae3a6803fab506000000',
'7' => '50a2adfc6803fab306000000',
)),
```

and there is another embed array which is from another user,lets call this second array

```
'_id' => new MongoId("508bef9e6803fa6305000000"),
'a' => 
array (
'0' => '508bf3766803fa810f000000',
'1' => '50a2ae616803fab706000000',
'2' => '50a2aeac6803fa150b000000',
),
```

what I want to do is to substract second array from first array, but I want to do It with mongodb

```
'a' => 
array (
'0' => '508bef9e6803fa6305000000',
'1' => '50901eac6803fafb0d000000',
'4' => '50a2ae846803fa140b000000',
'6' => '50a2ae3a6803fab506000000',
'7' => '50a2adfc6803fab306000000',
),
```

I tried different queries but could not get the result like this one,thank you for any help :)

```
$lk = $m->kud->user->findOne(
array(
"_id" => new MongoId("508bef9e6803fa6305000000"),'$nin'=>array("a"=>$ho["a"])
), 
array("_id" => 0, "a" => 1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not currently support projections based on value matching (it will eventually).  For a case like this, you may need to return the whole document and then pull out the values client-side.

Comment: I am doing an app like twitter to develop myself, what I want to do here, when a user looks up to another user's followers, I am intending to show if the user follows that user or not, I dont want to send query in foreach loop, do you have any other idea ? how can I manage this ?

Comment: Which part of the query are you worried about putting in a forEach loop?  I'm also not sure if it will help, but you may want to look at the [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/) operator for queries.